# Why does the Google Pay for Android IsReadyToPay request return false?

Tags: android, google-pay

Here is the JSON request that I am sending:

```json
{
  "allowedPaymentMethods": [
    {
      "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
        "allowedCardNetworks": ["MASTERCARD", "VISA"]
      },
      "type": "CARD"
    }
  ],
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "apiVersionMinor": 0,
  "existingPaymentMethodRequired": true
}
```

The [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) Google Pay object documentation says that setting the optional `'existingPaymentMethodRequired'` property to `true` should always give me a `true` response on the test environment. However, I am getting a `false` response.

Removing `'existingPaymentMethodRequired'` also gives me a `false` response and setting it to `false` gives me a `true` response only when `PAN_ONLY` is available.

I have confirmed that I am on the Google Pay test environment and, although I have a card added to my device through the Google Wallet app, I am also unable to get a `true` response when only using `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS`.

I have even made successful test environment purchases by setting `'existingPaymentMethodRequired'` to false and using `PAN_ONLY`.

Am I missing something or is it Google's problem?

Comment: does your (test-) card support the auth methods you have specified? If the card does not support those, it will not work. especially 3D-Secure is still not available on  all credit cards.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the latest version of the [Google Pay API Sample App for Android](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) on a number of devices and I'm seeing the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) method return `true` for me regardless of the `"existingPaymentMethodRequired"` value when (1) the Google Pay environment is set to [ENVIRONMENT_TEST](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_TEST) and (2) the `"allowedAuthMethods"` array is set to `["PAN_ONLY","CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]`.

I suggest you try out the [Google Pay API Sample App for Android](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) and shoot a message to the [Google Pay Developers Network](https://twitter.com/GooglePayDevs) if it doesn't work for you as expected.